# Windows 2012 redirection of Com Ports for RDP connections

Tags: windows-server-2012, remote-desktop-services

I am running windows 2012 with Remote Desktop Services

How do I get my local windows 7 pc comport to redirected to an application running on the windows 2012 server.

(I have enabled all local devices and resources in the more tab – of local resources in the Remote Desktop connection)

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is making sure port redirection is enabled [on the client in the Remote Desktop Connection settings](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc738524%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) and [has not been disabled via group policy or tsconfig.msc on the server / session host side](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc775863%28v=ws.10%29.aspx).

Note that Windows Server 2012 installations no longer come with a tsconfig.msc. If you want to check the current COM port redirection setting, you might want to use a Windows client (7/Vista/XP) with the Adminpak installed or a Server 2008R2/2008/2003 with Terminal Services installed to run tsconfig.msc to connect to your Server 2012 RD session host.